# Send email automatically with Power Automate when user enter new item in a list. But need a layout in the body of the mail

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a new flow with Power Automate that when a user creates a new item in a sharepoint list.
In the body of the email i have put the content of certain columns of the list. But it is just all plain text. Is there a layout that i can use or make my own using HTML. I hope i have explain my question right.
Gr. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can format the body as you wish. You didn't say which connector you're using, but the `Mail` and `Office 365 Outlook` connectors include HTML as their body format by default. You can use standard HTML tags, i.e.

```
<b>[List Column Value]</b>
```

Here's one such documented example:

[Creating an HTML Email using MSFlow and Data from DevOps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Creating-an-HTML-Email-using-MSFlow-and-Data-from-DevOps/ba-p/245966)